# Реализация LFSR (РСЛОС)

Tags: java, c++

Использовался регистр на 16 бит, конфигурация "Фибоначчи".

Для работы программы сначала вводится ее имя, далее имена:

1. исходный файл;
2. выходной, файл для записи ключа и флаг "-cod" - закодировать
   исходный файл, "decod" - декодировать.

Кодирование происходит нормально, а при декодировании первоначальный текст не получается.

Программа переписана с языка "Java", там работа корректна.

Язык С++ изучаю несколько месяцев, всего не знаю. Возможно ли какая-то ошибка из-за типов `char`, `std::string` и их преобразований?

Программа на java [здесь](http://ideone.com/nHTKdI). Запускается также, как и на С++. Также, не против послушать другие советы по поводу кода, так как только учу язык.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime> // содержит time()

void coding(char *); //кодирование, принимает путь к файлу
int binToDec ( const char* ); //преобразование строки в число
void overlayGamma(int); //наложение гаммы, принимает 16-битный ключ
void decoding(char * ch); //декодирование, принимает ключ к файлу

std::ofstream keyIn; //запись ключа
std::ifstream keyOut; //чтение ключа

char * pathIn; //путь к файлу ключа
char * pathOut; //путь к файлу ключа

    int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    if(argc!=5){
        std::cout << "\nШифрование: lfsr In.txt Out.txt. Key.txt -cod, где\n"
            << "In - файл, который требуется зашифровать\n"
            << "Out - файл, куда будет записан шифрованный текст\n"
            << "Key - файл, куда будет записан 16-битный ключ\n"
            << "-cod - команда шифрации\n"
            << "\nДешифрация: LFSR In.txt Out.txt. Key.txt -decod, где\n"
            << "In - файл, который требуется расшифровать\n"
            << "Out - файл, куда будет записан расшифрованный текст\n"
            << "Key - файл с 16-битным ключом\n"
            << "-decod - команда дешифрации\n";
        return -1;
    }
    //файл для шифрования
    std::ifstream in(argv[1], std::ios::in);
    if(!in){
        std::cout << " Файл " ;
        std::cout << argv[1] << " не найден";
        return -2;
    }
    //пути к файлам с ключом
    pathIn = argv[1];
    pathOut = argv[2];

    if(! strcmp(argv[4], "-cod")) coding(argv[3]); //шифрация, передаем путь ключа
    else if(! strcmp(argv[4], "-decod")) decoding(argv[3]); //дешифрация
    else {
        std::cout << "\nЗадан неверный флаг " << argv[3] << " , допустимы"
        << " -cod, -decod";
        return -3;
    }
}

int * getKey(){ //получение 16-битного ключа в двоичном виде
    int * key = new int[16];
    std::srand(time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
            key[i] = rand()%(2);
    return key;
}

long getGamma(int * key){ //получение гаммы, используя уникальный ключ
    int n = sizeof(key);
    std::string g = "";
    int S = 0;
    for(int t = 0; t <32; t++){ //гамма 32 бита
        //гамма получается с использованием регистра сдвига и конфигурации Фибоначчи
        S = key[n-1];
        S = ((( (S >> 15) ^ (S >> 4) ^ (S >> 2) ^ (S >> 1) ^ S ) & 0x00000001 ) << 15 ) | (S >> 1);
        for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--) //сдвиг ячеек регистра
            key[i] = key[i-1];   
        key[0] = S;  //запись сформированного бита
        if(S>0) g += "1"; //формирование гаммы в в двоичном виде
        else g += "0";      
    }
    return binToDec (g.c_str()); //вернуть гамму в 10 СС
//  (16, 5, 3, 2, 0)  - степени

}

void overlayGamma(int gamma){    //наложить гамму на открытый текст
    std::ifstream in(pathIn, std::ios::in); //открытый текст
    std::ofstream out(pathOut, std::ios::in); //для шифрованного текста
    char ch;    
    while(in.get(ch))
        out << (char)(ch ^ gamma); //наложение          
}

int binToDec ( const char* c) {
    int rez=0; 
    int a=1;  
    int len=strlen(c); 
    for(int j = 0, k = len; j < len; j++, k-- )      
        if ( c[ j ] == '1' ) rez |= a << k - 1; 
    std::cout << rez <<std::endl;
    return rez; 
}

void coding(char * ch){ //шифрование текста
    int * key = getKey(); //ключ 16 бит
    //запись ключа в файл
    std::ofstream keyIn(ch, std::ios::in);
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        keyIn << key[i];    
    keyIn.close();
    overlayGamma(getGamma(key)); //наложение полученной гаммы на открытый текст
}

void decoding(char * ch){ //декодирование текста
    int * key = new int[16];
    std::ifstream keyOut(ch, std::ios::in); //поток для чтения ключа
    std::string temp = "";
    const char * k;
    if(keyOut) //получение ключа из файла
        std::getline(keyOut, temp);
    else {
        std::cout << "Файл с ключом" << ch << " не найден.";
        exit(-1);
    }
    int lim = strlen(temp.c_str()); //длина ключа
    k = temp.c_str();
    for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        key[i] = (int) k[i]; //записываем ключ в массив
    overlayGamma(getGamma(key)); //наложение гаммы для расшифровывания текста
    keyOut.close();
}
```

Comment: Возможно и со строками ошибка. Попробуйте на буфере unsigned char.

Comment: @Roman, спасибо большое, проблема была действительно в этом, все получилось!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по java-коду, у вас ключ в файле записан в виде строки из цифр. Но в c++ коде вы неправильно считываете ключ из файла, `key[i] = (int) k[i]` не превратит символ `'1'` в число `1`.